# When not to reply to a recruiter as it would be clear that it is a waste of time?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, recruitment, careers

I have not been actively searching for a job, but I received an email from a recruiter saying that he wants to talk to me about some specific clients of his and asked my updated resume.  Although I am not looking to switch jobs right now, I would not want to miss a good opportunity. The thing is, I don't have any experience with recruiters, and I don't know what's normal.

In her email she did not mention anything about:

1. why she contacted specifically me
2. what skills/previous experience make me an eligible candidate for her clients.

If I erase my name from her mail and put anyone else's name not a single word from her mail would need to change.  Is this an indication that this would be a waste of time for me?  Or do usually recruiters just have a template and sent out for a first contact?

Comment: 1). There's a high chance that 1000 of other people got the same email. 2). You'll get a lot of those things during your career.

Comment: I don't understand downvoting without a comment.How is it any of any use or help?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recruiter is soliciting business. Don't take it personally. It's true that she doesn't know you from Adam but I know even less about you than she does. If you want to talk to her, talk. If not, keep your peace.

If you don't meet her clients' expectations, then she'll put your resume on the shelf. Again, nothing personal. That's how she makes her living and there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I understand it is her way to make a living.My only concern was if it is worth putting some time to update my resume just for this person since I wasn't planning to actively look for a new job just yet

Comment: @Jim It's really your choice - I keep my resume up to date whether employed or unemployed. However, if I am employed and I am not getting a clear picture as to how I am going to update my resume, I hold off on updating until I get that picture. Again, that's my choice. Updating the resume is not only due diligence, it's a chance for me to think over what I want to do going forward.